# Relative path to absolute path in Elisp

Tags: emacs, elisp

Having a relative path, how do I turn it into an absolute one from the location where the elisp file that I'm loading is. That is, I have an elisp file that I'm loading, it has an relative path and I need an absolute one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
'file-truename
```

From the documentation:

> Return the truename of FILENAME, which
>   should be absolute. The truename of a
>   file name is found by chasing symbolic
>   links both at the level of the file
>   and at the level of the directories
>   containing it, until no links are left
>   at any level.

The other solution proffered ('expand-file-name) leaves symbolic links in place, which may or may not be what you want.  'file-truename uses 'expand-file-name, so they both will determine the path relative default-directory for the buffer (which is what you're asking for).

After seeing the comment/question to a different answer, the problem is that the default-directory is that of the buffer that is calling 'load.

Luckily, there's a variable that 'load sets that stores the path to the file being loaded.  Try this snippet of code out:

```
;; this is in the file being loaded
(let ((default-directory (file-name-directory load-file-name)))
   (file-truename "blih"))
```

Comment: `file-truename` does more than what the user asked for.  I think they want `expand-file-name` instead.  @pupeno: yes it works just as well for directories.  BTW, in the GNU project, we use "file name" to mean what you called "path" and we keep "path" to refer to things like `load-path` or `$PATH` which are lists of directories (typically used to search for particular files).

Answer (score 16):

I ended up using:

```
(expand-file-name "relative/path" (file-name-directory load-file-name))
```

Comment: If you want to be extra robust, you can use `(file-name-directory (or load-file-name buffer-file-name)`. This will work when either loading the file or evaluating the code in it using e.g. C-x C-e.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `expand-file-name` function to convert a relative filename or path into an absolute filename/path.  Look [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Expansion.html#File-Name-Expansion) for additional information.

Comment: The problem is that when I load ~/blah/bleh.el and it evaluates (expand-file-name "blih") I end up with ~/blih instead of ~/blah/blih. I need it relative to where the file is, not to where I happen to be when I load the file.
Thanks.